Docopt only accepting extended format for option in Rust
Trying to learn rust to create a database manipulator. I currently have the following code:
extern crate sqlite;
use std::env;
use docopt::Docopt;
use serde::Deserialize;

fn main() {
    const USAGE: &'static str = "
        Usage: BobBot [-c | --create-database] <filename>
        Options:
            -c, --create-database  Create the database if it does not exist.        ";

    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    struct Args {
        arg_filename: String,
        flag_create_database: bool,
    }

    // Get the arguments passed to run the command.
    let argv = || env::args().collect::<Vec<_>>();

    // Parse argv - return error message on failure
    let args: Args = Docopt::new(USAGE)
                     .and_then(|d| {
                          d.argv(argv().into_iter()).deserialize()
                      })
                      .unwrap_or_else(|e| e.exit());

    println!("{}", args.flag_create_database);
    println!("{}", args.arg_filename);
}

running cargo run -- --create-database test.db returns the following:
true
test.db

running cargo run -- -c test.db returns the following:
false
test.db

I would expect both to return the former's output.
I have already attempted running the binary directly, to no effect.

FYI: the docopt crate is unmaintained and archived. It probably shouldn't be used for new projects.

@PitaJ What would you suggest instead? I am new to Rust so I am not entirely sure where to look for this information.
Edit - beat me to it. Appreciated!

clap is the most popular argument parsing library for rust.

In case someone else sees this - I followed @PitaJ's advice and switched to clap. The following code provides the functionality I was intending with the added benefit of looking cleaner.
use clap::Parser;

fn main() {

    #[derive(Parser, Debug)]
    #[command(version, about, long_about = None)]
    struct Args {

        filename: String,

        #[arg(short, long)]
        create_database: bool,
    }

    let args = Args::parse();

    println!("{}", args.filename);
    println!("{}", args.create_database);
}

